# ProjectReference.RootDir takes wrong project path

Tags: msbuild

I am using ProjectReference.RootDir to get path of particular project that is located in References. Example: %(ProjectReference.RootDir)

As soon as I am adding second project as reference ProjectReference.RootDir tries to get path from last added project, but not that one that I need.

Could anyone say how to get path of a particular project from project reference?

Comment: `ProjectReference` is an [Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-items?view=vs-2022) which is a collection. But you can't index into an Item. `%(ProjectReference.RootDir)` is [batching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-batching?view=vs-2022). If you are setting a property, you are essentially redefining the property for every value of `RootDir`. When you use the property, you have the value from the last definition. Can you provide an example of how you are using `%(ProjectReference.RootDir)`? Are you setting a property?